# ANR - Context.StartForegroundService

Tags: android

I have an app that has a foreground service, and I occasionally get this ANR:

Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

However, I have checked my code, and I don't call `startForegroundService()` anywhere. Only StartService when binding my Service to my main Activity.

Is there something else that can call `Context.StartForegroundService()`?

I've already tried to mitigate this by adding startForeground in my service onCreate and in onStartCommand. But it still continues to pop up.

Edit: Here are the merged manifest services:

```
     <service
        android:name="com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.HeapAnalyzerService"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:process=":leakcanary" />

     <service
        android:name="com.squareup.leakcanary.DisplayLeakService"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:process=":leakcanary" />
      <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
      </service>
      <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
      </service>
      <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

      <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: Libraries that you use that have services might use `startForegroundService()`. Check the Merged Manifest sub-tab in the manifest editor in Android Studio, and see if there are `<service>` elements that do not point to your own classes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for replying - I just edited the original post with everything that isn't my own class that is a service. Let me know if anything sticks out.

Comment: Make sure that you are on the latest versions of the libraries. For example, Leak Canary has had some updates related to their use of services with an eye towards these Android 8.0+ changes.

Comment: Leak Canary is on the latest version, so is Firebase. The only thing that was out of date was the android support libraries, I moved from 27.0.2 to 27.1.0

Comment: Hmm... scroll backwards in LogCat and look for debug/info messages about services being started for your app. It should be within 10-15 seconds of the error that you're seeking.

Comment: I don't even see the error myself - it only shows up on Google Play. Let me see if i can get it to show up in the sim. edit - yeah can't repro. I guess i just need to buy an android O device. It doesn't affect ALL of my Android O users so I really have no idea what it is.

Answer (score -1):

`startForegroundService(Intent service)` is `abstract` method.
Similar to `startService(Intent)`, but with an implicit promise that the Service will call `startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)` once it begins running.
[see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I know what it is. I don't call it in my code, and I'm already calling startForeground as soon as possible in any case (in oncreate, onStartCommand, etc)